# DOS Assembly - swapping values in bubblesort

Tags: assembly, dos, nasm, swap

I am trying to implement bubblesort in 16b dos assembly (I am using NASM). My program successfully generates table of 1024 random 16b numbers, now I have to sort them in descending order, I decided to use bubblesort, but my way of swapping them isn't working the way I think it should. Here is the code for swapping two numbers:

```
mov ax, [table+di]
cmp ax, [table+di+1]
jae dont_swap
mov bx, [table+di+1]
mov [table+di+1], ax
mov [table+di], bx
```

It is supposed to just swap a number that 'di' is pointing to with the next one in the table. It's hard for me to explain the effect so just look at some output the program gives:

```
-first few randomly generated numbers: 61923, 48369, 17084, 52802, 49358
-after sorting: 28482, 17007, 16962, 16962, 16962...
```

It just repeats the last number. Values after sorting aren't even in the original table.
I am certain that the problem isn't outside the code I presented, because if I remove it, recompile the program it perfectly repeats the generated table.

EDIT
Big thanks for everyone who contributed. The problem was not scaling offsets accordingly to variable's size. Table stores word variables while I iterated through bytes.

Comment: apart from your problem, which is probably the result of you doing byte wide access of word length data, you can simplify: rather than reading from table for comparison, and then read again the value which is still in a register, simply reuse that one. keep it in register for a whole sort pass, unless swapped. there is an XCHG instruction for that purpose. Simplification can help because it reduces complexity, and a bug is easier found in fewer remaining instructions.

Comment: My usual recommendation would be to take baby steps - start with a table of 2 numbers that aren't in correct order and make sure your code works for those. Then change it so that they're already in order and make sure that that works. Then move up to 3 elements, and try all permutations and make sure that the sort works for all of those. *then* you should decide whether to jump to 1024 numbers and/or randomizing the entries.

Comment: Think of what bubble sort needs to achieve in one pass not in terms of "swapping", but in terms of "finding highest/lowest number".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're comparing and swapping words you need to scale your offsets accordingly. The next element will be 2 bytes after the current element, i.e. at `[table+di+2]`.

You haven't shown us how you're calculating/updating `di`, so don't forget that it also needs to be moved 2 bytes per element.

Comment: The table is declared this way:

    table times 1024 dw 0

Does your advice still apply?

Comment: Yes. The declaration really only says how much storage you're reserving for the array. `table` is effectively an address for a storage of 2048 bytes that can hold any kind of data. What matters is how you access that address in your code. If you try to read/write words from/to it you need to use addresses that are 2 bytes apart because that's the size of a word on x86 processors.